# Can inputstream read the bytes of a password protected/corrupt file

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I'm using javamail to read the file and save the attachment to a local directory. I sent a password protected file & a corrupt file to the mail & my code didn't throw any exception, is this expected ?

```
Multipart multipart = (Multipart) message.getContent();
MimeBodyPart part =  (MimeBodyPart) multipart.getBodyPart(1);
byte[] dataInBytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(part.getInputStream());
String base64Data =  Base64.encodeBase64String(dataInBytes))
```

Comment: A file is just a sequence of bytes. Even if it contains encrypted or corrupt data it's still nothing more than a byte sequence. An inputstream doesn't differentiate or discriminate in any way. Bytes are bytes.

Answer (score 0):

> is this expected?

Yes it is expected.  Not it should not be a concern<sup>1</sup>.

The bytes are just bytes.  Java and the Javamail APIs make no distinction based on how they were created.

The file encryption will (should!) stop someone from reading the *unencrypted* bytes ... unless they know the password.  However, there is nothing to stop someone with legitimate or clandestine access to the email, at rest or in transit, from reading the encrypted bytes.  And the Javamail APIs don't try to do that either<sup>2</sup>.

---

<sup>1 - ... unless the encryption or the password are *weak*.  But then you are most likely *already* screwed ... because someone could have intercepted the email in transit.  Irrespective of what Javamail does.</sup>

<sup>2 - If you think about it, that would imply that the Javamail API would need to be involved in the decryption process.  And you would *need* to supply your password or decryption keys to Javamail to get your file from the email attachment.  That would be a *real* security concern!</sup>